# File not downloading using Google Drive Rest API V3

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've upload sqlite file to google drive for backup purpose. Uploading is working fine. But download code not work. I want to download this for re-import this database file into my app. I'm following Google Drive Rest Api v3 official documentation and copy code from that but dont work.

I've already give all type of scopes into oAuth consent screen and enabled Google Drive Api from developer console thats why upload file working fine.

code:

```
  public Task<Void> downloadFile(String fileId) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + java.io.File.separator + "test.db");

            mDriveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            return null;
        });

    }
```

what i'm missing and how to resolve this issue?

Note: i've logged file Id which gives correct file id. i.e. file id: `1NeUxYzCeyo_YZCqkLnOOmD2kP5PBLnxq`

Comment: Which documentation are you following? The Drive api v3 uses driveService and not mDriveService: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem like that what I did was using

```
files().list
```

for find my file like

```
public Task<Void> downloadFile(String fileId){
        OutputStream outputStream = new 
            FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + 
            java.io.File.separator + "test.db");
        return Tasks.call(executor, new Callable<File>() {
            @Override
            public File call() throws Exception {
                FileList list;
                File file=null;
                list=driveService.files().list().execute();
                if (list!=null&&!list.isEmpty()) {
                    for (File f : list.getFiles()) {
                        if(f.getId()==fileId)
                            file = f;
                    }
                    if (file!=null)                
                        mDriveService.files().get(file.getId())
                        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);    
                }    
            }
        });
    }
```